# Is there non-cacheable (=cache-bypass) load or store instruction for aarch64?

Tags: assembly, arm, memory-address, arm64, cpu-cache

In sparc architecture, there is ASI (address space indicator) that is passed to load, store instruction so if ASI is 0x20, cache is bypassed like it's IO access. Even if the memory range is set to cacheable at the page table, cache is bypassed. This is sometime very convenient like when synchronizing between cores using variable, etc.
Is there something similar in aarch64 architecture? I've looked through the instruction content but couldn't find any in the load/store instruction list.

Comment: Is it the non-temporal load and store `LDNP/STNP` you want?  But these are not for synchronizing between cores, but rather for accessing memory that won't be needed again in the near future and so for performance should not be cached.

Comment: Bypassing cache sounds unusual; are you talking about a many-core SPARC that isn't cache-coherent?  Normally bypassing the shared last-level cache would hurt performance, not help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. My intention is when a memory is not cache coherent, to let one processor write a data and another read it to synch the processing. I didn't know the LDNP/STNP bypasses cache. I'll try that instruction in in-line assembly. @NateEldredge you can make your comment your answer then I can select it.

Comment: Could someone here check my question related to using ldnp instruction please?  :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686942/aarch64-inline-assembly-error-operand-2-must-be-an-integer-register-ldnp-x

Comment: I thought the memory range was non-cacheable but it turns out it is cache coherent. I set the memory value using gdb and the core sees the updated value. The memory attribute was set 'inner-shareable' and I guess this makes the memory region cache coherent between the core and gdb port? (or is gdb action done throught core?)

Comment: Yes, inner-shareable implies cache-coherency, I think.  At least I know that cores you can safely run threads of the same process on (and thus have coherent shared memory) are expected to be in the same inner-shareable cache domain, as far as how C++ std::atomic stuff maps to asm instructions for acquire / release / seq_cst barrier instructions.  https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ARMv8 does not have such instructions. Load/Store instructions access memory depends on mapping attributes.

Mentioned `LDNP` and `STNP` instructions are not intended to by-pass cache.

> The Load/Store Non-temporal Pair instructions **provide a hint** to the memory system that an access is non-temporal or streaming, and unlikely to be repeated in the near future. This means that data caching is not required. However, depending on the memory type, the **instructions might permit memory reads to be preloaded and memory writes to
> be gathered to accelerate bulk memory transfers**. (Arm Architecture Reference Manual)

So cache still might be involved.

On top of that Cortex-A53 TRM, for example, explicitly states that cache would be involved.

> Non-temporal loads
> Cache requests made by a non-temporal load instruction (LDNP) are **allocated to the L2 cache** only. The allocation policy makes it likely that the line is replaced sooner than other lines.

For cores syncronisation you might check ARMv8 manual for lock implementations (aka atomic) and spin-lock.

As a side note, check your chip documentation. Plenty of modern chips have special hardware capabilities to provide hardware based cache-coherent interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up. I thought I'd use 'cache bypass read or write' between cores (because I'd been working on a system which doesn't provide cache coherency for some years) but ARM provides cache-coherency between cores so those kinds of instructions don't seem necessary.