# aarch64 Inline assembly error : operand 2 must be an integer register -- `ldnp x0,[x0]'

Tags: c, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm trying to write a simple function using in-line assembly and use it in a C program
The `mem_io_read` is a function that reads a memory address bypassing cache (event though the address is located in a cacheable memory region). It's for aarch64 machine.

```
static inline int mem_io_read(unsigned long paddr)
{
    unsigned long val;
    register pa;
    __asm__ __volatile__("mov %0, %1\n\t" : "=r" (pa) : "r"(paddr));   <-- move paddr to a register pa
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldnp %0, [%1]\n\t" : "=r" (val) : "r" (pa));   <-- load data from addr in pa
    return val;
}

main()
{
...
  uint32_t SCP_WR_ADDR     = &scp_wait; // where test1val was located. //x06000000;
  uint32_t chk_scp_rd_data = 0;

  // Send flag for proceeding SCP test
  (*(volatile uint32_t *)(SCP_WR_ADDR)) = 0x87654321;   <-- send signal to the other processor (scp)

  // Receives flag from SCP
  while(chk_scp_rd_data != 0x12345678)   <--- read back until the value is changed (reverse order)
  {
     chk_scp_rd_data = mem_io_read(SCP_WR_ADDR);
  }
}
```

When I compile this using gcc, I get this error

```
/tmp/ccCpQGc5.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccCpQGc5.s:26: Error: operand 2 must be an integer register -- `ldnp x0,[x0]'
```

I can't figure out what is wrong here. Please help.

ADD : from Peter Cordes's comment, I changed it to this one. It is compiled ok.

```
static int inline mem_io_read(unsigned long paddr)
{
    int val, val1;
    __asm__ __volatile__("ldnp %0, %1, [%2]\n\t" : "=r" (val), "=r" (val1) : "r" (paddr) : "memory");
    return val;
}
```

Comment: `ldnp` of course loads a *pair*, hence the name, so it has 2 output regs.  Google `aarch64 ldnp` and look at an instruction-set reference for it.

Comment: Also, your inline asm is missing a `"memory"` clobber.  (Although I guess if you never read or write that memory location with C, there shouldn't be any problem.)  It's also completely pointless to use `mov` instead of letting the compiler pick whatever reg `paddr` was in.  (Unless you want to truncate it to `register int`, given your `register pa` declaration?)  Your first asm statement already requires the compiler to have `paddr` in a register, so why not just use that as the input for the load?

Comment: @PeterCordes I see. I just thought ldnp is just the non-cacheable version of ldr. and didn't know I don't have to mov the input explicitly to a register. and Thanks for the "memory". I fixed it and it compiles ok at least. (you can make it your answer then I can select it).

Comment: The `n` part is the non-cacheable; is there no `ldnr` NT equivalent to `ldr` like there is `ldnp` for `ldp`?

Comment: The `n` part does _not_ stand for non-cacheable. It stands for non-temporal. The manual says "data caching is not _required_", but it's still very much allowed, and I would expect that if the data is already in a cache, then it will absolutely be fetched from there.

Comment: @PeterCordes: As far as I can tell it's pairs only.  I guess the idea is that non-temporal accesses are most useful when reading/writing large blocks, so they've only provided the largest-sized loads and stores, assuming you'll be looping anyway.  Of course, if you only want 64 or 32 bits, you can use the zero register to discard the half you don't want: `ldnp x0, xzr, [x2]` or `ldnp w0, wzr, [x2]`.  If you want to store 64 bits, you can split it over two 32-bit registers and `stnp w0, w1, [x2]`.  If you want to store 32 or fewer bits, you are out of luck.

Comment: Incidentally, `LDNP/STNP` also come in a SIMD version where you can load/store a pair of 32/64/128-bit SIMD registers.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Oh, right, these aren't intended for MMIO (because you'd make the region uncacheable and use ldr for that), and a 16-byte transfer is probably the same speed as an 8-byte transfer from DDR4.  Still possibly inconvenient if you want to load 4 bytes from an address that might only be 4-byte aligned (especially a possible page-split).  For 8 bytes, you might use `ldnp w0, w1, [mem]` / `orr  x0, x0, x1, lsl 32` - it does cost 1 extra ALU operation, and needs an extra scratch register, but cheaper than branching on odd/even multiple of 8 and choosing whether to load x0,xzr or xzr,x0.